# React Native: trying to pass a reference function via props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a reusable FlatList component which implements pagination, I'm trying to pass via props a plain function which is inside a mobx store which makes an axios call and retrieves data from backend to populate the FlatList, however I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: [endAction] is not a function
```

Also this one:

```
TypeError: [store][action] is not a function
```

In my mobx file I have:

```
async getVenueReviews(payload)
    {
        return await http.get(env.BASE_URL+'/api/venues/get-venue-reviews', {params:payload});
    }
```

This is how I pass props to my custom component:

```
<RList1 store='venueStore' action='getVenueReviews' endAction={venueStore.getVenueReviews} data={[]} renderItem={itemView}></RList1>
```

And this is how I call the function (two ways, both give me same TypeError...):

```
let response = [store][action]({ params : params });
let response = [endAction]({ params : params });
```

My full custom component, just in case:

```
export default RList1 = observer((props) => 
{
    
    const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);
    const [ loader, setLoader ] = useState(0);
    const [ page, setPage ] = useState(1);
    const [ paginate, setPaginate ] = useState(2);
    const [ pagination, setPagination ] = useState(null);
    const [ numberOfPages, setNumberOfPages ] = useState(10);

    const { id=1,store,action,endAction, ...rest } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('RList1 mounted');
        onEndReached();
    }, []);

    const onEndReached = async () =>
    {
        if(page < numberOfPages)
        {
            setLoader(0);
            try 
            {
                setLoader(1);
                console.log('fetching data');
                let params = { id:id, page : page, paginate : paginate };
                let response = [store][action]({ params : params });
                //let response = [endAction]({ params : params });
                setData([...data, ...response.data.data.data]);
                setPagination(response.data.pagination);
                setNumberOfPages(response.data.pagination.last_page);
                setLoader(2);
            } 
            catch (error)
            {
                setLoader(3);
                throw error;
            }
        }
    };
    
    return(
    <View style={{ flex:1 }}>
        <FlatList  style={{ flex:1,backgroundColor:'rgb(235,235,235)'}}  data={data} keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()} extraData={loader}
        onEndReached={ ()=>{ onEndReached() } } onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        {...rest}
        />
    </View>
    );
        

});
```

Comment: whats that [store][action]({ params : params }) ? do you want to call function from above code?

Comment: My bad, it's actually a reference to a function in one of my mobx stores, not a mobx action but a plain function defined in my venue mobx store

Comment: can you please create demo of your problem in codesandbox ?

Comment: I think that you shuld inject store to component that need it and call it directly. [store][action] what is this ? [] create array or let accest to property object by passing string or nubmer.  What you  try doing in that way can you explain ?